# Python not working after trying to upgrade to a newer version of Python

Tags: python, software-installation

Ok, this is totally my fault. I should not have tried to install and compile Python 2.75. After everything went haywire, I saw someone on this site caution against doing this very thing.

I am running Django and it was working fine until the upgrade attempt. I then managed to switch the default version from 2.73 to 2.75 and by doing a `make install` within the python dir. When I checked the version running the OS said 2.75, so I figured great it worked. NOT SO. Django then stopped working.

I attempted to switch back to 2.73 and that seemed to have worked. However, now I get python errors showing that Django, PIL etc are not installed. So, I thought to try and re-install them and I get these messages "Requirement already satisfied" and that the packages are in the dist-packages dir in the python 2. 7 directory. What happened? How do I fix this?

I have tried creating a running a simple test script containing this code:

```
    from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
    print(get_python_lib())
```

and it worked. So, I know python 2.73 is functional, but my libraries including Django do not work still. I tried adding `import site; site.getsitepackages()` to one of my python scripts that uses PIL and i still get this error:

```
File "display.py", line 6, in <module>
from imgProcess import imgProcess
File "/var/www/opengov/imageXMLtoCVSTestPY/imgProcess.py", line 3, in <module>
from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I have tried running `sudo pip uninstall PIL` to see if maybe re-installing it might clear the error. It asks if i want to proceed, naturally i say yes and it says it was removed. Now when i `ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL` I see that it is still there and when i try to sudo pip install PIL, it of course says it is already there. What????

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 12.04

Comment: Is there a way to back-track in version 12.04 without using "Back In Time"?

Comment: Please, stop doing that. You are just digging yourself deeper.

Comment: @Braiam Doing what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using virtualenv.

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

[Here](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/) is a great tutorial on how to set up self-contained python environments with different versions of python as well as different packages. In addition, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837723/django-virtualenv-layout) is a SO Q&A where they also address the usage of virtualenvwrapper. I hope this aids anyone else who may have gotten a bit too curious for their own good with Django and Python as far as updating and configuration. ;) Oops. Lesson learned. If you find this helpful kindly give it the old thumbs up, thanks.